# Excel VBA macro upload and downloading through FTP

Tags: excel, vba

Please tell anyone how to do uploading and downloading csv files through ftp using Excel VBA macro.Can anyone please point me to any example or sample code .I want to copy that file to unix location.

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: What have you tried?  At least do a google search and see if you can implement any of the ideas you find: if you have problems then post the actual code you're trying to use.

Comment: @Tim: I tried in google and haven't find any information on this.

Comment: vb6 and vba share the same code for upload and downloading through FTP. Search Google for "vb6 code upload file ftp"

Comment: Siddarth: I want it using Excel Macro.Is it same?

Comment: I want to copy to the Unix location.

Comment: Siddarth:but all the samples are connecting to internet application.Can you point me to one sample please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here involve a _specific_ programming problem. Simply asking for code is frowned upon. A search of Stack Overflow turns up [several examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+ftp) which you can adapt. If you are still unable to complete the code, post a new question, show the code you are using and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: How can i use .cls file in EXCEL.

Answer (score 3):

If you have *Microsoft Internet Transfer Control* as an available library this looks like the most elegant solution: http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/ftp_upload_file.html

Otherwise the most common solution involves executing shell commands: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?471016-Import-an-FTP-file-into-Excel